# IL emit - operation could destabilize runtime when storing then loading

Tags: c#, cil

Hey, so I have the following IL:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Which works fine. It basically returns the argument given.
This, however:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Does not work. It crashes with the exception "Operation could destabilize the runtime.".
Now, I know that the purpose of that is useless but I'm trying to reach my goal by small steps.
Why does that not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you declared the local? Does the type of arg0 and loc0 match? Also you know that arg0 in an instance method is the this reference, right?

Comment: D'oh, that was stupid (I wasn't declaring the local). Thank you a lot!