# Calling private constructors with Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, cil

I'm trying to emit the following IL:

```
LocalBuilder pointer = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(IntPtr));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, pointer);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, pointer);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(IntPtr).GetMethod("ToPointer"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The delegate I bind with has the signature

```
void* TestDelegate(IntPtr ptr)
```

It throws the exception

> Operation could destabilize the
>   runtime.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Alright, so I got the IL working now. The entire goal of this was to be able to call a private constructor. The private constructor takes a pointer so I can't use normal reflection. Now.. When I call it, I get an exception saying

> Attempt by method <built method> to
>   access method <private constructor>
>   failed.

Apparently it's performing security checks - but from experience I know that Reflection is able to do private stuff like this normally, so hopefully there is a way to disable that check?

Comment: Your IL looks OK. Try writing it to an assembly on disk (go via `AssemblyBuilder`); *peverify* will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Very weird. If I use AssemblyBuilder and generate all that, the method works fine. If I use DynamicMethod, it throws that exception, despite the methods having the exact same IL. Hmm..

Comment: Alright, so I got the IL working now. I have edited my post with a new question.

Comment: edited my answer since you edited the question.  Out of curiosity, what did you have to change to make the IL verify?

Comment: I used the AssemblyBuilder, ModuleBuilder, TypeBuilder and MethodBuilder. When I did that it worked fine, but with DynamicMethod (despite it being the exact same IL instruction) it could "destabilize the runtime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually arg-0 is the `this` pointer, not the `IntPtr` in your parameter list.

EDIT: To answer your new question, you need to use one of the other `DynamicMethod` constructors.  For example, the [`DynamicMethod Constructor (String, Type, Type[], Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z84bd3st.aspx) is described as "logically associated with a type. This association gives it access to the private members of that type."

Comment: And, you were already told this in [the answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528452/il-emit-operation-could-destabilize-runtime-when-storing-then-loading/4528463#4528463)

Comment: I don't know how the dynamic method handles instance/static methods, but I do believe the dynamic method is a static method and therefore doesn't have a this pointer.
I realize I didn't say it was a DynamicMethod - sorry about that.

Comment: @Jakob: show your code which create the `DynamicMethod`, I think which constructor you are using, and the parameter type list you are passing in, may be important to figuring this out.

Comment: also, you could have just used [`Ldarga`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldarga.aspx), unless you wanted to make a copy of the parameter.

Comment: @Ben: I used Ldarga the first time, but switched it out when it didn't work (I pretty much copied/pasted from the compilers output of the wanted code).
Here is the code: http://pastie.org/private/yap1h9t5sys3bgurjqcwxq

Comment: @Ben: When I used that constructor, the IL with DynamicMethod verifies fine. It should be working now. Thanks!